# Inserting array returning incomplete data (MySQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have an insert command based on the following:

```
$baseINS = "INSERT INTO table2 (Points_ID, StaticCode) VALUES ";
$arrayINS = explode(", ", $arraystring);
foreach ($arrayINS as &$array1INS) {
    $array1INS = "('" . $array1INS . "', '123456')";
}
$arrayvaluesINS = implode(', ', $arrayINS);
$insertSQL2 = $baseINS . $arrayvaluesINS;
```

The `$insertSQL2` is queried from the following transaction:

```
$insertSQL = "BEGIN";
mysql_query($insertSQL) or die (mysql_error());
$insertSQL = $insertSQL1;
mysql_query($insertSQL) or die (mysql_error());
$insertSQL = $insertSQL2;
mysql_query($insertSQL) or die (mysql_error());
$insertSQL = "COMMIT";
mysql_query($insertSQL) or die (mysql_error());
```

(where `$insertSQL1` is another SQL insert, to another table)

Table structure as follows:

> `table2`
>    (   `ID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `StaticCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
>   `Points_ID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
>   UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB

Now, let's say for example that `$insertSQL2` echos as `INSERT INTO table2 (Points_ID, StaticCode) VALUES ('24859', '123456'), ('24649', '123456'), ('25166', '123456')`

I would expect three rows to appear in the table2 ...but this is what happens:

- Both the insert commands (`$insertSQL1` and `$insertSQL2`) do, in fact, insert data.
- It's just that, while `$insertSQL1` inserts all of the data from all of the form to the required fields in table1, the `$insertSQL2` (which is inserting the array) doesn't - it just inserts the static code, once, and leaves the Points_ID blank.

I have tested the INSERT statement by just copying the echoed command into PHPMySQL, and it does exactly what it is supposed to, so I know that my version of MySQL can handle it.

Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to show your table structure. e.g. is `Points_ID` a foreign key field? do the matching foreign records exist? Your code is also vulnerable to SQL injection, you're using a very dangerous foreach() construct, and your actual query calls are needlessly verbose. e.g. clean up your code and maybe things will start working.

Comment: @MarcB - this is just a proof of concept at present (hence messy code). Table structure: ` `table2` (
  `ID` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StaticCode` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Points_ID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB `

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks your are using mysql extension. You should use mysqli or pdo_mysql. I believe transactions don't work on mysql.

mysqli would look almost same, but for transaction use  [mysqli features](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php)

```
/* set autocommit to off */
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);

/* Insert some values */
$mysqli->query($insertSQL);

/* commit transaction */
$mysqli->commit();
```

Comment: Would this explain why it is performing the most part of the INSERT INTO command, but not all? Surely it would either work or not work?What I'm getting is some information being inserted, and some information not getting inserted. (I agree that I will probably upgrade it to mysqli throughout, but just wanted to get my head around the actual problem, too!) :-)

Comment: What I was saying is that "BEGIN" and "COMMIT" in this case have no effect, so yes, some information can be inserted, but not all of them, if there is any problem.